# Issue while validating with PSR-2 on Prestashop Validator

Tags: php, validation, controller, prestashop, psr-2

While validating my new module on Prestashop Validator, I am getting the following error in my main controller file (php file).

```
End of line character is invalid; expected "\n" but found "\r\n"
```

I am getting the error on the first line that only has the starting `<?php` tag.

I have researched so much about it on the Internet but unable to find a solution for it. I am struck.

What should I do?

Comment: Please add respective code as well.

Comment: I am getting this error on the starting first line with <?php tag only.

Comment: do you have empty lines at the beginning of your file??

Comment: No i dont have any empty line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++, first go to View --> Show Symbol --> Show All Characters

All characters including spaces, tabs, and new lines (CR LF).

Hit Ctrl + H for "Find and Replace."

In "Find What," look for "\r\n"

Replace with "\n".

Click "Replace All"

All CR's should now be removed and should fix the error.